# How to get rid of tensorflow verbose messages with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying out the tensorflow Keras backend.  It keeps printing these overly verbose messages to the terminal which kind of ruins the the output of the probar logger. Such as the following.

```
h 1/200
   4608/3629568 [..............................] - ETA: 849s - loss: 1.1816I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:244] PoolAllocator: After 4208 get requests, put_count=4193 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.238493 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.264971
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:256] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
```

How can I make tensorflow quite?  I have been looking through the documentation and I can't find anything like a .theanorc file for settings.

Comment: Hope this is helpful...
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/566

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TensorFlow 0.12, you can set the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to filter out log messages. For example, you can start `python` this way to avoid the `INFO`-level messages (such as the "Raising pool_size_limit_"  message in your quest):

```
$ TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1 python ...
```

Comment: Where are these log levels documented?

Comment: check this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging/set_verbosity